# choose color to draw life in pygame

Tags: python, colors, pygame

I want to draw the player's life with a `pygame.Surface` filled with a color:
green means that the player's life is close to the player max life and red when the player's life is low and i don't know how to pick the color.
The green has to turn slowly red as the player's life decreases.

Comment: Please add a code example of what you have tried and use [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask something on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a colour changing rectangle (or any other shape), then pygame has some very useful `draw` commands

Take this, `pygame.draw.rect` taken from [the pygame docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect)

```
pygame.draw.rect()
    draw a rectangle shape
    rect(Surface, color, Rect, width=0) -> Rect

Draws a rectangular shape on the Surface. The given Rect is the area of the 
rectangle. The width argument is the thickness to draw the outer edge. If 
width is zero then the rectangle will be filled.
```

In this case, `color` will be a 3 element tuple for red, green, and blue colour values. These will all be between 0 and 255. For example, (255, 255, 255) would be pure white.

If you keep track of a `health` and a `max_health` variable then you can find out how much of the rectangle should be red and how much should be green.

For example

```
green_value = 255 * (health / max_health)
red_value =   255 * ((max_health - health) / max_health)
```

Say your health was at 20 out of a maximum of 100, then your green value would be 20% of 255, and your red value would be 80% of 255, and your `pygame.draw.rect` function would take in a `color` parameter of `(red_value, green_value, 0)`

As long as you remember to update the `green_value` and `red_value` variables you should be fine.